# Is it possible to use java 7 syntax with JAXX Framework?

Tags: java, swing, java-7

I can not use java 7 syntax, such as diamond, in my classes if I generate some GUI classes using [JAXX Framework](http://jaxx.nuiton.org).

Is there a way to make this works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer : Yes since [Version 2.24](https://forge.nuiton.org/versions/724), (more precisely since the issue [Issue 3668](https://forge.nuiton.org/issues/3667) and [Issue 3669](https://forge.nuiton.org/issues/3668).

Note that JAXX does not understand everything of the java 7 (nor java 8), but can manage to parse method prototype, class signatures and field declaration.

You can not use in a binding for example a lambda, or...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer @Tony Chemit. I will trey this version.